# i wana get sum of balance column data using between date and sum of balance column not between dates ,group by customer_id in mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, between

here is my mysql table like this,

```
customer_id   balance  date
1                300   1-1-2018
2                200   3-1-2018
1                100   5-1-2018 
2                50    5-1-2018   
1                30    6-1-2018   
1                10    7-1-2018 
4                50    7-1-2018
```

I want this result if I select from date 1 to 5

```
customer_id    current       previous     total   
1               400           40           440    
2               250            0           250      
3               0             50           50
```

Comment: You are asking to pivot results. Do you know the dates at the time of the query? That would be simpler. Reference [UNION](/questions/12113699/) and [CASE](/questions/6605604/) and those might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with a pair of subqueries that compute the aggregate values. So you can select the sum within the specified date range and the sum outside that range using subequeries. Then add `coalesce` to replace `null` with a valid amount (0).

```
select
  customer_id,
  coalesce(current, 0),
  coalesce(previous, 0),
  coalesce(current, 0) + coalesce(previous, 0) total
from
(
  select
    customer_id,
    (
      select sum(balance)
      from balance b
      where b.customer_id = a.customer_id
        and b.date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-05-01'
      group by b.customer_id
    ) current,
    (
      select sum(balance)
      from balance c
      where c.customer_id = a.customer_id
        and c.date not between '2018-01-01' and '2018-05-01'
      group by c.customer_id
    ) previous
   from balance a
) c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id
     , sum(a.balance) as current
     , sum(b.balance) as previous
     , sum(a.balance) + sum(b.balance) as total
  from mytable as a
    join mytable as b on a.id = b.id
 where a.date between date('2018-01-01') and date('2018-05-01')
   and b.date < date('2018-01-01')
group by id;
```

Please be aware that you probably want to base the date ranges on variables.